# jsPlumb - how to deny connection (detach) if target or source is specify?

Tags: jsplumb

I'm new in jsPlumb, I'm plaing with [demos](http://jsplumb.org/demo/statemachine/dom.html). I need not to allow the connection when the target or source is specify. I mean: when the target is X - connection can't be establish.

Comment: can you create a fiddle to play with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsPlumb fires an event `connection` when a connection is made.

```
jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(info) {
    if(info.sourceId==='abc'){
      jsPlumb.detach(info.connection);
    }

});
```

info is an object with the following properties:

```
connection - the new Connection. you can register listeners on this etc.
sourceId - id of the source element in the Connection
targetId - id of the target element in the Connection
source - the source element in the Connection
target - the target element in the Connection
sourceEndpoint - the source Endpoint in the Connection
targetEndpoint - the targetEndpoint in the Connection
```

References :

http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/events.html#evt-connection-detached
http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/removing.html
http://www.jsplumb.org/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#method_detach

Comment: you can accept it as an answer by clicking on the `tick`

Comment: As of the new version of JsPlumb community edition;  "jsPlumb.detach is not a function". Now it is jsPlumb.deleteConnection(connection) as per this posted issue: https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb/issues/905

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an Interceptor: the beforeDrop event to be specific.

"This event is fired when a new or existing connection has been dropped."

```
jsPlumb.bind('beforeDrop', function(connection) {
    if(connection['targetId'] === 'theEndPointName') {
       alert('Connection Denied!');
       return false;
   }
   return true;
});
```

When you return false, the connection will be dropped.

Documentation: https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/community-2.x/current/articles/interceptors.html